# C++: "Distance" between 2 coordinates in 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, pythagorean

For a game I'm writing I need to **find an integer value for the distance between two sets of coordinates**. It's a **2D array** that holds the different maps. (Like the original zelda). The further you go from the **center (5,5)** the higher the number should be since the difficulty of enemies increases. Ideally it should be **between 0 and 14**. The **array is 11x11**.

Now, I tried to use the **pythagoras** formula that I remember from highschool, but it's spewing out **overflow numbers**. I can't figure out why.

```
        srand(rand());
        int distance=sqrt(pow((5-worldx), 2)-pow((5-worldy), 2));
        if(distance<0) //alternative to abs()
        {
            distance+=(distance * 2);
        }
        if(distance>13)
        {
            distance=13;
        }

        int rnd=rand()%(distance+1);

        Monster testmonster = monsters[rnd];
```

Comment: first of all, sqrt returns a double, so distance should be a double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`srand(rand());` does not make sense, it should be `srand(time(NULL));`

don't use `pow` for square, just use `x*x`

your formula is also wrong, you should add number together not minus

`sqrt` return `double` and cast to `int` will round it down

i think `sqrt` always return positive number

you know `abs` exists right? why not use it? also `distance = -distance` is better than `distance+=(distance * 2)`

```
srand(time(NULL));

int dx = 5 - worldx;
int dy = 5 - worldy;
int distance=sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
if(distance>13)
{
    distance=13;
}

int rnd=rand()%(distance+1);

Monster testmonster = monsters[rnd];
```

Comment: thank you. Very silly mistake there. The reason I use srand(rand()) is because the project does a lot of random things, and using it with time everytime sometimes happens so fast that the clock hasn't changed, and it gives me the same randoms. using the previous random as the seed avoids this. I tried the if instead of abs() because I suspected it was the problem.

Comment: you only need to call `srand` once only, not everytime you want to use `rand`

Comment: With a static seed like rand() that would give the same result each time though.

Comment: @Cinaed666 consider using c++'s random function.  
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution

Answer (score 0):

It's a^2 + b^2 = c^2, not minus.  Once you call sqrt with a negative argument, you're on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You're subtracting squares inside your square root, instead of adding them ("...-pow...").